# Set up D3 with react-create-app

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, webpack, package.json, create-react-app

I am working on a React project using react-create-app as a starting point. I am attempting to integrate D3 into my project but I am having difficulty getting D3 to work.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/crypto) is my project as it currently stands. I have created a React component in d3-2.js and have imported it to App.js but it isn't working. It appears D3 is coming back undefined.

Other posts here have mentioned importing **import * as d3 from 'd3'**. I've tried that and it still isn't working.

Is it a matter of setting this up in webpack's files? I have installed d3 via **npm install d3 --save** and it's in my package.json file.

Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It's technically not a syntactically correct React component you've imported, there's no render method or any constructors.

You would want to at least create a component like this:

```
class myD3Component extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        //d3 code that modifies the svg in render() here
    }
    render() {
       return (<svg ref={d => (this.svg = d)}/>)
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/alanbsmith/react-d3-example/blob/master/src/ProgressArc.js for a more concrete example.

Comment: missing `return`

Comment: React Faux DOM (https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom) is a neat little library that avoids the need for `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Chart` component inside the file `d3-2.js` is not a valid React component:

```
class Chart extends React.Component {

var url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=200&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG";

// continues...
}
```

You need to create a `render()` function at a minimum, or you could use a [stateless functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components):

```
const Chart = (props) => {
  var url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=200&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG";    
  // etc...
}
```

In your CodeSandbox you also have another component inside `d3.js` which looks fine - this is the model to go with.